# How to open a folder on a remote Windows server (from a Linux server), get a file list, and store the values in an array

Tags: perl

I have a program that copies backup files from a Linux server to a Windows NAS server every week. There is a script setup on the Linux server to delete the files locally after a month. I want to add an extra layer of checks, to ensure that the currently existing files on the Linux server exist on the Windows server before they're deleted.

I figured the best way to do this would be to do a LS in the directory of the Linux server, store the values to an array, do the same on the windows server, and ensure that every file on the Linux side, exists on the Windows side prior to the delete.

Perl isn't something I work with almost ever, so I'm looking for guidance on how to ask the script to establish a remote connection, and get a file list/store to an array.

Can anyone provide some guidance?

Comment: What's wrong with [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/)?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with that. It looks like it may do exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

### Use rsync Instead

Rather than reinvent the wheel in Perl, it might be better to use a well-tested tool that already exists for the purpose. I would recommend using [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/), with or without an SSH tunnel.

Rsync supports a [number of options](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) for deleting files from the source or destination. For example:

```
 --delete                delete extraneous files from dest dirs
 --delete-before         receiver deletes before xfer, not during
 --delete-during         receiver deletes during the transfer
 --delete-delay          find deletions during, delete after
 --delete-after          receiver deletes after transfer, not during
 --delete-excluded       also delete excluded files from dest dirs
 --remove-source-files   sender removes synchronized files (non-dir)
```

Another alternative is [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/), but rsync is (IMHO) easier to script and configure. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: @ikegami There's more than one way to do it, but you could run rsyncd or sshd as a service under [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) if you want. If you run sshd, you don't need to run rsyncd as a service at all; just pass `-e ssh` to rsync on the client side. --You might also find [this tutorial](http://www.gizmoplex.com/wordpress/ssh-and-rsync-within-cygwin/) useful, or find others that fit your needs better via your search engine of choice.